# How to display pdf document in android mobile browser? the pdf document is correctly displaying in my PC

Tags: android, pdf, browser, view, element

I'm able to display a pdf document in my PC browser page using  but the problem is when I'm trying to load the same web page on the android browser is showing me a file name to open it instead of showing it. When I place open button then the pdf is downloaded. What can I do? please help since my application is only designed specifically for android tablet.

````
  <iframe id="auto-height-doc" src="{!! asset('storage/'.$document->docPath) !!}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>```
````